# PostgreSQL: Accent/diacritic insensitive search

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to do a query on PostgreSQL that will ignore accents on the columns?

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ILIKE 'ivan'
```

I want a query like the one above to return records whose `name` is 'Iván', for example.

Comment: What version of the database and what encoding is your string? There's been a lot of bugs and changes in the character set encoding functions throughout most of 8.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find either of these solutions useful:

- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strip_accents_from_strings
- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strip_accents_from_strings,_and_output_in_lowercase

Comment: Thanks! I also found I could use the `TRANSLATE` function.

Comment: can you expand on this usage of the `TRANSLATE` function?